# How avoid "esc" event and input by keyboard number, in the ui panel in a FloatPorperty?

Tags: python

By default FloatProperty showed in panel can inset number by keyboard input, and if press esc return at the previus value, how to avoid?

Comment: Hi. So we are able to understand your problem better, are you able to explain why you need that?

Comment: Hi Ray, Because i have a problem with update function in update function i created a subtraction from 2 FloatProperty ,work fine but work bad if press esc and input a value from input value in panel , I do not care to have the input in the interface neither less than when I press esc it returns to the previous value, I wondered if there was a method to avoid this otherwise I have to change the function, In addition I wondered if it was possible at the time of the mouse release to return the floatproperty to the default value